# How to get the sound on a VMware ESXi virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

We are using VCSA 6.7 with five ESXi 6.7 hosts and multiple VMs are are running inside the ESXi hosts.

I have no sound card installed on the ESXi hosts but we need sound from VMs. Can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no sound card is needed on the ESXi host. The VMWare virtual sound driver installed with VMTools (or the Microsoft "Remote Audio" driver) will be utilized to pass sound from the VM. I'm seeing "Remote Audio" as my audio device via RDP on a Windows Server 2019 VM on ESXi 6.7. Not certain if the hardware has sound on the chipset but it certainly doesn't have a discrete card.

Comment: Thanks duct_tape_coder for your quick response, My problem is that how can we get audio from vm, without using RDP?

Comment: Do you not get audio when using the VMware remote console?

Comment: I am getting audio when using with remote control, but we need audio simple opening vm from web console or through browser

Comment: I am getting audio when using with remote control, but we need audio simple opening vm from web console or through browser

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://communities.vmware.com/thread/571763

Comment: Hi  duct_tape_code....... We are getting audio through "vmrc" but we need audio from vm, when opening with web console.

Comment: @03amittrivedi on reading through that thread, I was given the impression their workaround worked for the web client and not just the VMRC. I have not tested it myself. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, I have tested it from by following your article (communities.vmware.com/thread/571763 ), it is working by using vmware workstation, but we need sound without using "VMRC" & "VMware Workstation".
Can we get sound without using VMRC & VMWare Workstation?

Comment: Hi, Need your kind input regarding the issue

Comment: If that doesn't work, I don't know. Try opening a support ticket with VMware.

Comment: Ok...Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory legal note: I work for Dell

To answer the question in the OP: yes, no soundcard is required on the ESXi host itself as the sound card is virtualized.

To answer the question as elaborated on in the comments, there is no way to get sound via the webconsole. If you want sound you have to connect with Workstation to your ESXi or vCenter/RDP/etc.

A VMWare employee confirms this here: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vSphere-Host-Client-Discussions/How-to-enable-sound-in-ESXi-host-VMs-when-I-access-them-via/td-p/2812687